# RoomDB - JOIN query for which the result is a list of data types with a field whose value is a multiplication of 2 tables fields

Tags: android, sql, android-room

Let's say I have the following entities for my RoomDB:

```
enum class Type {
    FOO,
    BAR
}

@Entity(
    tableName = "amount",
    primaryKeys = ["id", "type"]
)
data class Amount(
    val id: Long,
    val type: Type,
    val amount: Int
)

@Entity(
    tableName = "value",
    primaryKeys = ["id", "valueType"]
)
data class Value(
    val id: Long,
    val valueType: Type,
    val value: Int
)
```

What I want to do is somehow, with a SQL query (or RoomDB annotations ideally...) query the `amount` table, and join each amount with the corresponding value row(s) from the `value` table (using the `type` from `amount` to cross reference the `valueType` field on the `value` table) by multiplying the `amount` field with the `value` field to end up with an object like this:

```
data class ValueOfAmount(
    val type: Type,
    val valueOfAmount: Int // amount * value
)
```

I can think of a way to do this, but it requires doing some of the JOIN "logic" in my repo code layer, when I'd prefer to do this at the query layer instead (if at all possible).

Create a joined data class like so:

```
data class AmountWithValue(
    @Embedded
    val amount: Amount,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "type",
        entityColumn = "valueType"
    )
    val value: Value
)
```

Expose a function from my dao to retrieve the joined data:

```
@Query("SELECT * from amount")
suspend fun getAmountsWithValues() : List<AmountWithValue>
```

Consume this function, and map the results to `ValueOfAmount` instances like so:

```
val valueOfAmounts = dao.getAmountsWithValues().map { amountWithValue ->
    ValueOfAmount(
        amountWithValue.amount.type,
        amountWithValue.amount.amount * amountWithValue.value.value
    )
}

// Do stuff with value of amounts
```

What I'd like to know is if there is some way to encode that mapping code into the QUERY itself (either via SQL or, even better, if RoomDB has some annotations that support this kind of complex query as annotations on my data types - similar to how it let's me define relationships for simple JOIN operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following may be what you want:-

First a Class to be joined :-

```
data class AmountWithCalculatedValue(
    @Embedded
    val amount: Amount,
    val calculatedValue: Int
)
```

And then a Dao :-

```
@Query("SELECT *,(amount * value) AS calculatedValue  FROM amount JOIN value ON amount.type = valueType")
    fun getAmountWithCalculatedValue(): List<AmountWithCalculatedValue>
```

if you wanted the Value as well it's a little more complicated due to duplicate/ambiguous columns but you could use:-

```
data class AmountWithCalculatedValue(
    @Embedded
    val amount: Amount,
    val calculatedValue: Int,
    @Embedded(prefix = "_value_")
    val value: Value
)
```

With :-

```
@Query("SELECT amount.id, amount.amount, amount.type,value.id AS _value_id, value.id AS _value_value, value.valueType AS _value_valueType,(amount * value) AS calculatedValue  FROM amount JOIN value ON amount.type = valueType")
    fun getAmountWithCalculatedValue(): List<AmountWithCalculatedValue>
```

or :-

```
@Query("SELECT amount.*,value.id AS _value_id, value.id AS _value_value, value.valueType AS _value_valueType,(amount * value) AS calculatedValue  FROM amount JOIN value ON amount.type = valueType")
    fun getAmountWithCalculatedValue(): List<AmountWithCalculatedValue>
```

- that is using the @Embedded's prefix parameter is saying that the values will be prefixed with the prefixed with the prefix so you have to us *AS* clauses to disambiguate the respective columns. As no prefix is used on the amount columns then amount.* can be used (2nd dao).
- I'd say that for 1-1 relationships using @Relationship (as opposed to @Embedded) is perhaps a little less efficient than using a JOIN. As the way Room works it gets the Parent's from the given query and then retrieves the @Relation from the Parent via a separate query and hence why it recommends @Transaction.

Comment: Ta Mike - I'll check this out in the morning, appreciate the answer (and on the previous question - cheers for taking the time dude)